# how to make get user specific posts in django

Tags: django

I am creating a web app where users are allowed to post stuffs and i have a profile section where i want users to see the stuffs they have posted so i am using IF loop in django.

```
{% if user_post.author  == "request.user.username" %}
    hello there {{user_post.title}}
{% else %}
    againnn
    {{user_post.author}}
    {{request.user.username}}
{% endif%}
```

here in the if loop i am checking for all the authors and comparing them with the user logged in.
but it is not executing, in the else part i am confirming names of the user . but the else part is executing.
i am not sure if it can be done this way..if not please suggest me a way
thanks

Comment: Why is `"request.user.username"` a string?

Comment: {% if user_post.author  == request.user.username %} this is also not working

Answer (score 0):

how about change the codes.

```
{% if user_post.author  == "request.user.username" %}
```

to

```
{% if user_post.author  == request.user.username %}
```

Comment: @AbhishekSharma You have to pass the `request` object to the template, just as you're doing with `user_post`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman sorry but i didnt understand...please explain.